# Deploy TextFairy but when build gradlew see error

Tags: java, android, ocr

I tried to deploy code from https://github.com/renard314 but, when I build with command: gradlew build then see error

```
Information:Gradle tasks [:app:clean, :app:generateDevelopDebugSources, :app:prepareDevelopDebugUnitTestDependencies, :app:mockableAndroidJar, :app:generateDevelopDebugAndroidTestSources, :app:assembleDevelopDebug]
signing.properties not found
:app:clean
:app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:preDevelopDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:checkDevelopDebugManifest
:app:preDevelopReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:prePlaystoreDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:prePlaystoreReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:tess-two:tess-two:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:tess-two:tess-two:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:tess-two:tess-two:compileReleaseNdk UP-TO-DATE
:tess-two:tess-two:compileLint
:tess-two:tess-two:copyReleaseLint UP-TO-DATE
:tess-two:tess-two:mergeReleaseProguardFiles UP-TO-DATE
:tess-two:tess-two:packageReleaseRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:tess-two:tess-two:checkReleaseManifest
:tess-two:tess-two:prepareReleaseDependencies
:tess-two:tess-two:compileReleaseRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:tess-two:tess-two:generateReleaseResValues UP-TO-DATE
:tess-two:tess-two:generateReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
:tess-two:tess-two:packageReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
:tess-two:tess-two:compileReleaseAidl UP-TO-DATE
:tess-two:tess-two:generateReleaseBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:tess-two:tess-two:mergeReleaseShaders UP-TO-DATE
:tess-two:tess-two:compileReleaseShaders UP-TO-DATE
:tess-two:tess-two:generateReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
:tess-two:tess-two:mergeReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
:tess-two:tess-two:processReleaseManifest UP-TO-DATE
:tess-two:tess-two:processReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
:tess-two:tess-two:generateReleaseSources UP-TO-DATE
:tess-two:tess-two:incrementalReleaseJavaCompilationSafeguard UP-TO-DATE
:tess-two:tess-two:ndkBuild
make: Entering directory `E:/phong.pham/Developer/TextFairy/textfairy/tess-two/tess-two'
[armeabi] Install        : libjpgt.so => libs/armeabi/libjpgt.so
[armeabi] Install        : liblept.so => libs/armeabi/liblept.so
[armeabi] Install        : libpngt.so => libs/armeabi/libpngt.so
[armeabi] Install        : libtess.so => libs/armeabi/libtess.so
[armeabi-v7a] Install        : libjpgt.so => libs/armeabi-v7a/libjpgt.so
[armeabi-v7a] Install        : liblept.so => libs/armeabi-v7a/liblept.so
[armeabi-v7a] Install        : libpngt.so => libs/armeabi-v7a/libpngt.so
[armeabi-v7a] Install        : libtess.so => libs/armeabi-v7a/libtess.so
[x86] Install        : libjpgt.so => libs/x86/libjpgt.so
[x86] Install        : liblept.so => libs/x86/liblept.so
[x86] Install        : libpngt.so => libs/x86/libpngt.so
[x86] Install        : libtess.so => libs/x86/libtess.so
[mips] Install        : libjpgt.so => libs/mips/libjpgt.so
[mips] Install        : liblept.so => libs/mips/liblept.so
[mips] Install        : libpngt.so => libs/mips/libpngt.so
[mips] Install        : libtess.so => libs/mips/libtess.so
[arm64-v8a] Install        : libjpgt.so => libs/arm64-v8a/libjpgt.so
[arm64-v8a] Install        : liblept.so => libs/arm64-v8a/liblept.so
[arm64-v8a] Install        : libpngt.so => libs/arm64-v8a/libpngt.so
[arm64-v8a] Install        : libtess.so => libs/arm64-v8a/libtess.so
[x86_64] Install        : libjpgt.so => libs/x86_64/libjpgt.so
[x86_64] Install        : liblept.so => libs/x86_64/liblept.so
[x86_64] Install        : libpngt.so => libs/x86_64/libpngt.so
[x86_64] Install        : libtess.so => libs/x86_64/libtess.so
[mips64] Install        : libjpgt.so => libs/mips64/libjpgt.so
[mips64] Install        : liblept.so => libs/mips64/liblept.so
[mips64] Install        : libpngt.so => libs/mips64/libpngt.so
[mips64] Install        : libtess.so => libs/mips64/libtess.so
make: Leaving directory `E:/phong.pham/Developer/TextFairy/textfairy/tess-two/tess-two'
:tess-two:tess-two:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac UP-TO-DATE
:tess-two:tess-two:processReleaseJavaRes UP-TO-DATE
:tess-two:tess-two:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForRelease UP-TO-DATE
:tess-two:tess-two:transformClassesAndResourcesWithSyncLibJarsForRelease UP-TO-DATE
:tess-two:tess-two:mergeReleaseJniLibFolders UP-TO-DATE
:tess-two:tess-two:transformNative_libsWithMergeJniLibsForRelease UP-TO-DATE
:tess-two:tess-two:transformNative_libsWithSyncJniLibsForRelease UP-TO-DATE
:tess-two:tess-two:bundleRelease UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportAnimatedVectorDrawable2321Library
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72321Library
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportCardviewV72321Library
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportDesign2321Library
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportRecyclerviewV72321Library
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42321Library
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportVectorDrawable2321Library
:app:prepareComCommit451PhotoView124Library
:app:prepareComCrashlyticsSdkAndroidAnswers1310Library
:app:prepareComCrashlyticsSdkAndroidBeta122Library
:app:prepareComCrashlyticsSdkAndroidCrashlytics264Library
:app:prepareComCrashlyticsSdkAndroidCrashlyticsCore2313Library
:app:prepareComCrashlyticsSdkAndroidCrashlyticsNdk112Library
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAnalytics840Library
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesBasement840Library
:app:prepareComSquareupLeakcanaryLeakcanaryAndroid131Library
:app:prepareComViewpagerindicatorLibrary241Library
:app:prepareIoFabricSdkAndroidFabric1314Library
:app:prepareTextfairyTessTwoTessTwoUnspecifiedLibrary
:app:prepareDevelopDebugDependencies
:app:compileDevelopDebugAidl
:app:compileDevelopDebugRenderscript
:app:generateDevelopDebugBuildConfig
:app:mergeDevelopDebugShaders
:app:compileDevelopDebugShaders
:app:generateDevelopDebugAssets
:app:mergeDevelopDebugAssets
:app:processDevelopArmeabi-v7aDebugManifest
:app:processDevelopUniversalDebugManifest
:app:processDevelopX86DebugManifest
:app:fabricGenerateResourcesDevelopDebug
:app:generateDevelopDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDevelopDebugGoogleServices
File google-services.json is missing from module root folder. The Google Quickstart Plugin cannot function without it.
:app:generateDevelopDebugResources
:app:mergeDevelopDebugResources
:app:processDevelopArmeabi-v7aDebugResources
:app:processDevelopUniversalDebugResources
:app:processDevelopX86DebugResources
:app:generateDevelopDebugSources
:app:preDevelopDebugUnitTestBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareDevelopDebugUnitTestDependencies
:app:mockableAndroidJar UP-TO-DATE
:app:preDevelopDebugAndroidTestBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareDevelopDebugAndroidTestDependencies
:app:compileDevelopDebugAndroidTestAidl
:app:processDevelopDebugAndroidTestManifest
:app:compileDevelopDebugAndroidTestRenderscript
:app:generateDevelopDebugAndroidTestBuildConfig
:app:mergeDevelopDebugAndroidTestShaders
:app:compileDevelopDebugAndroidTestShaders
:app:generateDevelopDebugAndroidTestAssets
:app:mergeDevelopDebugAndroidTestAssets
:app:generateDevelopDebugAndroidTestResValues UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDevelopDebugAndroidTestResources
:app:mergeDevelopDebugAndroidTestResources
:app:processDevelopDebugAndroidTestResources
:app:generateDevelopDebugAndroidTestSources
:app:incrementalDevelopDebugJavaCompilationSafeguard
:app:ndkBuild
[armeabi] SharedLibrary  : libhocr2pdf.so
[armeabi] Compile++ thumb: image_processing_jni <= PixBinarizer.cpp
[armeabi] Compile++ thumb: image_processing_jni <= SkewCorrector.cpp
[armeabi] Compile++ thumb: image_processing_jni <= image_processing.cpp
E:\phong.pham\Developer\TextFairy\textfairy\hocr2pdf\src\codecs\png.cc
Error:(47) undefined reference to 'png_get_io_ptr'
Error:(34) undefined reference to 'png_get_io_ptr'
Error:(41) undefined reference to 'png_get_io_ptr'
Error:(57) undefined reference to 'png_sig_cmp'
Error:(71) undefined reference to 'png_create_read_struct'
Error:(77) undefined reference to 'png_create_info_struct'
Error:(88) undefined reference to 'png_set_longjmp_fn'
Error:(90) undefined reference to 'png_destroy_read_struct'
Error:(96) undefined reference to 'png_set_read_fn'
Error:(104) undefined reference to 'png_read_info'
Error:(107) undefined reference to 'png_get_IHDR'
Error:(112) undefined reference to 'png_get_channels'
Error:(115) undefined reference to 'png_get_x_pixels_per_meter'
Error:(116) undefined reference to 'png_get_y_pixels_per_meter'
Error:(129) undefined reference to 'png_set_palette_to_rgb'
Error:(135) undefined reference to 'png_get_tRNS'
Error:(153) undefined reference to 'png_get_valid'
Error:(175) undefined reference to 'png_get_valid'
Error:(178) undefined reference to 'png_get_sBIT'
Error:(179) undefined reference to 'png_set_shift'
Error:(154) undefined reference to 'png_set_tRNS_to_alpha'
Error:(191) undefined reference to 'png_set_interlace_handling'
Error:(197) undefined reference to 'png_read_update_info'
Error:(200) undefined reference to 'png_get_rowbytes'
Error:(209) undefined reference to 'png_read_rows'
Error:(213) undefined reference to 'png_destroy_read_struct'
Error:(228) undefined reference to 'png_create_write_struct'
Error:(235) undefined reference to 'png_create_info_struct'
Error:(246) undefined reference to 'png_set_longjmp_fn'
Error:(248) undefined reference to 'png_destroy_write_struct'
Error:(255) undefined reference to 'png_set_compression_level'
Error:(260) undefined reference to 'png_set_write_fn'
Error:(279) undefined reference to 'png_set_IHDR'
Error:(284) undefined reference to 'png_set_pHYs'
Error:(286) undefined reference to 'png_write_info'
Error:(288) undefined reference to 'png_get_rowbytes'
Error:(292) undefined reference to 'png_set_swap'
Error:(300) undefined reference to 'png_write_rows'
Error:(303) undefined reference to 'png_write_end'
Error:(306) undefined reference to 'png_destroy_write_struct'
Error:error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [E:/phong.pham/Developer/TextFairy/textfairy/app/src/main/obj/local/armeabi/libhocr2pdf.so] Error 1
make: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
E:\phong.pham\Developer\TextFairy\textfairy\image-processing\src\image_processing_util.h
Warning:(32) warning: "LOG_TAG" redefined
 #define LOG_TAG "image processing (native)"
 ^
Information:(Unknown)
E:\phong.pham\Developer\TextFairy\textfairy\image-processing\src\image_processing.h
Information:(33) this is the location of the previous definition
:app:ndkBuild FAILED
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:ndkBuild'.
> Process 'command 'ndk-build.cmd'' finished with non-zero exit value 2
Information:BUILD FAILED
Information:Total time: 1 mins 6.862 secs
Information:42 errors
Information:1 warning
Information:See complete output in console
```